# authorize.net - Make transactions in Sandbox Account

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have a Sandbox Account and I made test transactions but all the payments failed. I do not have Live Account and cannot test in Test mode. Is there any other ways to test transactions?

Comment: Are you using the sandbox api url for making the requests? `https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api`. Also if authorization is correct then are you using test creditcards for payments? http://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/

Comment: How did they fail?  Was an error returned?

Comment: Here is what I get.
Error code: E00009.
Message: The payment gateway account is in Test Mode. The request cannot be processed.

Comment: Sandbox accounts should never be in test mode

Answer (score 0):

Googled for this and came up with [this url](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/What-does-error-E00009-mean/td-p/6):

> If you are receiving error E00009, “The payment gateway account is in
>   Test Mode. The request cannot be processed” while requesting the ARB
>   or CIM API, then your account is in Test Mode. Because the ARB and CIM
>   APIs do not function in Test Mode, you need to disable Test Mode
>   through the Merchant Interface.
>
> To do this, log into your account, click Settings under Account in the
>   left-side menu, then click Test Mode under the General Security
>   Settings section. From here, click Turn Test OFF to put your account
>   in Live Mode. Once you’ve done this, you should no longer receive
>   error E00009 when requesting the ARB or CIM API.